# Why unclear errors are generated after adding kotlin kapt?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I was using DataBinding in my project, but Android Studio showed a warning telling that kotlin kapt should be enabled. Ok, I added it and my app gradle file is like this now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
    /// some standard things 
  dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }

}

dependencies {
   kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.3"
}
```

And here is my project level gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
      repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
  }
}
```

After that, I builded by project and it showed following errors:

```
/some_path_here/android/my_package/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/my_package_path/MyFileName cannot find symbol interface_name_here
```

It is interesting, but the errors like above only occurs for interfaces. But not all interfaces in my project, only for couple of them. I don't know how to solve this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: just removed kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.3" from dependencies. It will work

Comment: No, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I solved my issue. I investigated that files where that error keeps happening. And it turns out that I didn't have `package` directive in that files. And I even deleted dependency of data binding compiler (I don't know is it needed to not).